# Permission denied error calling fopen

Tags: php

I use XAMPP on Leopard. I'm trying to create cache files using fopen but I get

```
Warning: fopen(/Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/cache/index.php.cache) [function.fopen]: failed to open stream: Permission denied in /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/mysite/functions.php on line 26
```

I tried to change folder permissions using CMD+I in finder and setting read/write access for everyone, but did not work.

Got any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change permissions for that file, no the folder.

Anyway, if you try to change permissions but can't do it, maybe that means you don't have permissions to chmod at all!

If you have administrative privileges, try *sudo chmod* in terminal.

Comment: PHP is running as admin.. so I had to change admin permissions on that folder!